# How is updating an Array working in scala?

Tags: scala

I am still sometimes puzzled by scala occasional syntactic magic.

I thought, that writing

`array(5)`

is just a shortcut for

`array.apply(5)`. (As is written in the documentation for Array.)

However, I can do quite happily

`array(5) = 3`

But I cannot do

`array.apply(5) = 3`.

What is going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are different rules on the left side of `=` : 
`a.x = b` is translated to `a.x_=(b)` (provided there is also an x() method) 
`a(i1,... in) = b` is transformed into `a.update(i1...,in, b)`

So `array(5) = 3` is `array.update(5,3)`

Of course, for arrays it is directly compiled to an array write without a method call in between.